# Question on my homework exercise in c# (cannot use arrays)

Tags: c#, if-statement, while-loop

I am having problems with my if statement to display the lowest mark in the class. Sometimes it works and sometimes not depending how I input the grades.

```
int n, count = 0, grade = 0, average = 0, highest = 0, lowest = 0, low = 0;
int classgrade = 0;
Console.Write("enter amount of students: ");
n = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
while (n != 0)
{
   Console.Write("enter student mark: ");
   grade = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
   count++;
   n = n - 1;
   classgrade = classgrade + grade;
   average = classgrade / count;

   if (grade > highest)
      highest = grade;
   else 
      low = grade;
   if (low < grade)
      lowest = low;
}
Console.WriteLine("Average mark: {0}",average);
Console.WriteLine("Highest mark: {0}", highest);
Console.WriteLine("Lowest mark: {0}", lowest);
Console.ReadLine();
```

Comment: Have a think about what will happen with your last `if` after `low = grade;` runs. _Pro-tip - remove the `low` variable. It is not helping you._

Comment: Also, if two people's grades are 52 and 53 what do you expect the average to be? What about if 51 and 52?

Comment: When is it working and when not?

Comment: Note: this is the perfect time to learn to debug. Run the code in a debugger line by line. Watch what happens and where things go differently from what you expect. Modify/fix and repeat.

Comment: It will probably help if you get rid of low and intialise lowest to a value higher than the maximum possible grade. Adjust your if else accordingly.

Comment: You overcomplicate things. You probably wouldn't even think about them the way your conditions are in real life. If a grade > highest, then it's your new highest. If a grade < lowest, then it's your new lowest. And, yeah, @stephanV has a point as well.

Comment: And of course Eric Lippert's [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)

Comment: And computing average may be better out side of the loop.

Answer (score 4):

There are a few problems in your code, and I've started to write a comment but it was getting too long, so I've converted this into an answer.

The first thing I've notices was that you are using `int.Parse` to get an integer value from whatever string the user is entering into the console.
This is a very common mistake, unfortunately - There is nothing stopping the user from entering a string that can't be parsed as an int, like `'asdf'` - and the `int.Parse` method will throw an exception whenever it tries to parse such a string.
Instead of `int.Parse`, you should use `int.TryParse` - this will simply return `false` if the string can't be parsed as an int.

The second thing I've noticed is that you have too many variables. For instance, the `count` variable is redundant since you already know that there are exactly `n` grades.
The `low` variable doesn't seem to serve any purpose at all as well.

Next, the `average` should be a `double`, not an `int`, to handle the very common situation where the sum of grades divided by the number of grades is not an integer.
Please not that this means that the `classgrade` variable must also be a `double`, otherwise `classgrade / n` is an integer division meaning you will get a rounded number as the average in such cases.

You also do not have any range validation on your input - nothing is stopping the user from entering negative numbers as grades (or even the number of grades).
Usually, grades are numbers between 0 and 100 - so you might want to add these validations. (Hint - use a different method to get the inputs from the user - one that will include the validations and allows the user to re-enter a value if it's invalid)

Finally, you start the `lowest` at `0` - so naturally, unless one of the grades *is* negative, the `lowest` will always stay `0`. It's starting point should be the highest possible value (so either `100` or `int.MaxValue`).

Having said that, I'm not going to post the code corrections you need to make - because if I do that, you will learn nothing from this.
The only way to learn how to do something is to actually do that something - so I'll leave the code writing for you to do.

Good luck and happy programming!

Comment: Upvote for such an in depth post, also for not giving the direct answer

Comment: @TheGeneral Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Just Remove the Else and change the comparison operator (the variable low isn't useful).

```
if (grade > highest)
    highest = grade;

if (count == 1)//to assign lowest at the first increment
    lowest = grade;

if (grade < lowest)
    lowest = grade;
```